# Delete something after the first of the line or a / (Regex)

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I'm attempting to remove something from a string using regex that matches substrings before /../ that either begin at the start or follow a / .

So far I have

```
re.sub('(?<=[/]|\A).+(?=[/][.][.][/])', '', str)
```

I keep getting errors though when I attempt this or other variations ranging from it deleting all items after the first / to not deleting the first character of the grouping.

Comment: Please provide example strings and the expected result, that would make it easier to understand.

Comment: That regex won't even compile because `(?<=/|\A)` is illegal in a Python regex (lookbehinds must be of constant width, and this matches either 0 or 1 characters).

Comment: Essentially, I want to take something like test/new/../ and return test//../  I've found that using a lookbehind will start at the first instance of a / and continue to the /../ whereas I want the closest instance of a / to the /../ and remove everything in between.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that `/` itself can never be part of the match. Therefore, try

```
re.sub(r'[^/]*(?=/\.\./)', '', mystr)
```

`[^/]` matches any character that isn't a `/`, so it starts matching at the start of the string until it encounters `/../`, unless there's a `/` in-between, in which case the match will start after that.

Comment: +1 you are correct, this way the lookbehind is not needed anymore.

Comment: Perfect thank you! Sometimes I forget you can do the inverse.